# Software (official or third party) to make a Dell laptop trackpad mimic touch gestures?

Tags: touchpad, gestures

Is anyone aware of / have seen discussions of software that can translate actions on a Dell TrackPad to emulate swipe actions similar to those on touch devices?

Or is the Dell TrackPad hardware incapable of providing any software with such input information?

It need not be complete and working perfectly, just curious if even beta/experimental software is out there.

Example features:

- Swipe (left, right, up, down) (maybe?)
- Two finger detection (seems unlikely)
- Pinch (zooming - this one seems highly unlikely)

For reference the Dell hardware I have is the Studio XPS M1640 and Precision M4500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three approaches possible :

1. Use the latest Synaptics driver
2. Use third-party software
3. Use a modded driver

The first point was covered by Journeyman Geek [above](https://superuser.com/questions/336709/software-official-or-third-party-to-make-a-dell-laptop-trackpad-mimic-touch-gue/337650#337650).

A third-party free software is [two-finger-scroll](http://code.google.com/p/two-finger-scroll/). Its use is described in the article
[How To Easily Activate Two Finger Scroll In Windows Laptops](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easily-activate-finger-scroll-windows-laptops/).

A modded driver is available from [Latest Synaptics driver modded for Acer MediaTouch](http://mobileprofessionalstool.blogspot.com/2011/01/latest-synaptics-driver-modded-for-acer.html).
Its use is described in the article
[HowTo: enable advanced gestures for Synaptics touchpads](http://en.community.dell.com/dell-groups/new-to-community/w/tutorials/howto-enable-advanced-gestures-for-synaptics-touchpads.aspx) (my link above is more recent than the one in the article).

Special care should be taken before installing the modded driver, such as ensuring backups and creating a system restore point. Although support is claimed for the Dell XPS, it is unknown whether is supports your exact model. In case of a problem, either rollback the driver in Device manager, or restore the system restore point.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all trackpads in modern use tend to be from synaptics, and there's apparently drivers floating around that support it. Apparently this includes the [latest official synaptics driver](http://www.synaptics.com/resources/drivers) and apparently the 1640 has support for [multitouch according to this thread at notebook review](http://forum.notebookreview.com/dell-xps-studio-xps/407994-new-synaptics-driver-multitouch-like-macbooks.html).

There's a load of dodgy looking drivers for the m4500 on google, but nothing that looks recommendable

Answer (score 0):

The latest Synaptics drivers don't appear to enable multitouch gestures for all users. There are posts over the internet saying this is the case since at least driver version 15.2.20, and I haven't had luck enabling the feature using the 15.3.x drivers.

It might help to try the registry route: http://nathanhinkle.com/blog/enable-synaptics-multitouch-gestures-in-google-chrome/ or older drivers: http://www.mydigitallife.info/unlock-and-enable-multitouch-gestures-on-synaptics-touchpad-or-trackpad-driver-download/